# No variance in binomial glmer yields problematic CI

Tags: r, confidence-interval, generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme, lsmeans

I have a `glmer` with a binomial response variable and two binary predictor variables, where there are no observations for one of the four groups. I used `emmeans` to calculate confidence intervals, and for this group obviously the mean and variance are zero. The model predicts a CI from 0 to 1, and **my question is whether the confidence interval and contrasts are calculated correctly when all observations and thus variance of a group are zero**. Please see details below. I have a total of 804 observations, so a bit much to include here. Should someone want to reproduce my models, I can share the data somehow.

The data concern observations of two female sharks in an aquarium. The response variable is presence/absence in a shipwreck (`in_wrak_inc`). Presence was recorded by multiple people (nearly twenty `observers`) every five minutes between 9:00 and 17:00 for many days (a few in early January 2021, and then intermettently from 2021-12-14 to 2022-01-19). As random effects, the model includes `observer` and `date`. As fixed effects, the model includes individual (either the first or second female shark, `jv` or `ov`), presence/absence of a male shark (`locatie_jm`, where `Kleine Oceaan` == absence) and there interaction.

```r
  individu locatie_jm    in_wrak_inc     n
1 jv       Kleine Oceaan nee            52
2 jv       Kleine Oceaan ja             27
3 jv       Oceaan        nee           213
4 ov       Kleine Oceaan nee            83
5 ov       Kleine Oceaan ja            165
6 ov       Oceaan        nee           177
7 ov       Oceaan        ja             87
```

As you can see there are no observations for `jv` when `locatie_jm == Oceaan` + `in_wrak_inc == ja`. My code is below.

```r
model_wrak1 <- lme4::glmer(in_wrak_inc ~ locatie_jm * individu + (1|datum) + (1|observant),
                           data = scans_vrouwtjes_wrak,
                           family = binomial)

summary(model_wrak1)

# Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
# Family: binomial  ( logit )
# Formula: in_wrak_inc ~ locatie_jm * individu + (1 | datum) + (1 | observant)
# Data: scans_vrouwtjes_wrak
# 
# AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
# 406.6    434.7   -197.3    394.6      798 
# 
# Scaled residuals: 
#   Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
# -1.7776 -0.0625  0.0000  0.0980  8.6087 
# 
# Random effects:
#   Groups    Name        Variance Std.Dev.
# datum     (Intercept) 26.32    5.130   
# observant (Intercept) 32.81    5.728   
# Number of obs: 804, groups:  datum, 27; observant, 16
# 
# Fixed effects:
#   Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
# (Intercept)                   1.9335     2.7759   0.697 0.486091    
# locatie_jmOceaan            -31.3131    66.9586  -0.468 0.640036    
# individuov                    1.1188     0.3358   3.331 0.000864 ***
#   locatie_jmOceaan:individuov  25.2350    66.9589   0.377 0.706268    
# ---
#   Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# Correlation of Fixed Effects:
#   (Intr) lct_jO indvdv
# locat_jmOcn -0.013              
# individuov  -0.115  0.000       
# lct_jmOcn:n -0.012 -0.999  0.000

model_wrak_emm_loc_ind <- emmeans::emmeans(model_wrak1,
                                           specs = pairwise ~ locatie_jm | individu,
                                           type = "response")

model_wrak_emm_loc_ind$emmeans

# individu = jv:
# locatie_jm      prob    SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
# Kleine Oceaan 0.8736 0.306 Inf  0.029111     0.999
# Oceaan        0.0000 0.000 Inf  0.000000     1.000
# 
# individu = ov:
# locatie_jm      prob    SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
# Kleine Oceaan 0.9549 0.119 Inf  0.086899     1.000
# Oceaan        0.0463 0.123 Inf  0.000208     0.919
# 
# Confidence level used: 0.95 
# Intervals are back-transformed from the logit scale

model_wrak_emm_loc_ind$contrasts |> confint()

# individu = jv:
#   contrast               odds.ratio       SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
# Kleine Oceaan / Oceaan   3.97e+13 2.66e+15 Inf      0.00  3.93e+70
# 
# individu = ov:
#   contrast               odds.ratio       SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
# Kleine Oceaan / Oceaan   4.36e+02 1.34e+03 Inf      1.05  1.82e+05
# 
# Confidence level used: 0.95 
# Intervals are back-transformed from the log odds ratio scale
```

[image: Figure 1. Estimated Marginal Means and 95% confidence intervals for being in the shipwreck for both female sharks in relation to location of the young male.]

Comment: I don't really understand why you consider the CI (0, 1), problematic. It is the most conservative CI possible (with guaranteed coverage), which seems appropriate if there is no information to derive a more narrow CI.

Comment: If there are many observations and all are negative, surely that is an indication it is somewhat likely the CI should be closer to zero than to one? In this case, the probability of the other group is 0.87, and I expect a difference in the contrasts.

Comment: Sure, but you would need to quantify "somewhat likely" to derive a more narrow CI. And you can't do that just based on the model.

Comment: I understand the model cannot do that (because there is no variance?). Can it be done based on the number of observations? I have 213 observations where `in_wrak_inc == 0`. Surely the likelihood of `in_wrak_inc == 1` is therefore lower than when I would have, say, only 15 observations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may find [this paper](https://academic.oup.com/aje/article/187/4/864/4084405) helpful.

This problem, sparse data in one or more cells of the cross-tabulation of your predictor and outcome variables (as you present above) which causes extreme parameter estimates, is referred to as *separation*. The solution is usually one or another form of regularization

(Alternatively, you can omit the covariate(s), which cause the separation, but I'll ignore that here).

There are several such options discussed in the linked paper. Potentially the easiest to implement would be data augmentation. Another option would be to estimate the model in the Bayesian framework. Using even modestly informative priors on the log odds ratios would provide the regularization needed to get  sane results (and narrower intervals).

You could try estimating the model with R package [*brms*](https://paul-buerkner.github.io/brms/). It uses the same syntax as lme4 so you wouldn't really need modify your model specification, you'd just need to add priors for the model parameters.

Comment: Thanks. That paper, and looking at separation in logistic regression generally, seems very useful. I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to answer my own question. The `lme4` package cannot deal with complete separation, but info how to fix it can be found [here](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#penalizationhandling-complete-separation) and [here](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/ecostats_chap.html#digression-complete-separation) (based on a question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63662660/complete-separation-how-to-impose-zero-mean-normal-priors-on-fixed-effects-i)). Running a mixed model with priors with `blme::bglmer()` did the trick. The priors I chose (10 for the intercept and 2.5 for the various slopes) are default.

```
model_wrak1_bayes <- blme::bglmer(in_wrak_inc ~ locatie_jm * individu + (1|datum) + (1|observant),
                           data = scans_vrouwtjes_wrak,
                           family = binomial, 
                           fixef.prior = normal(sd = c(10, 2.5)))
```

This gives the following emmeans, which I find very reasonable:

```
individu = jv:
 locatie_jm        prob       SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 Kleine Oceaan 0.092783 0.216260 Inf  6.65e-04    0.9402
 Oceaan        0.000234 0.000542 Inf  2.49e-06    0.0215

individu = ov:
 locatie_jm        prob       SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 Kleine Oceaan 0.269436 0.505533 Inf  2.40e-03    0.9826
 Oceaan        0.093029 0.198690 Inf  1.01e-03    0.9120

Confidence level used: 0.95 
Intervals are back-transformed from the logit scale
```